# Its automatic removes extra space in name between two words

Tags: spring, jsp

I am workin on my spring application here i am getting company object and then in display:column tag i am showing its id, name and all the properties.

```
<display:column sortable="true" title="Name" headerClass="sortable" sortProperty="name" style="width:20%">
    ${company.name}
</display:column>
```

name values is like "shitanshu   patel" but it shows on jsp page only a sigle space between shitanshu and patel like this "shitanshu patel".

Is this broswer functionality or something we need to implement for this.

Please suggest i am stucked here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser will collapse all whitespace into a single space. The prevent this behavior you can place a the name between `<pre></pre>` tags which will preserve the spaces.

Another option would be to replace the existing spacing with `&nbsp;` meaning non-breakable space.